# lodash find array in array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have 2 arrays

```
const arr1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
const arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I want to get the specific element in these array to log 
There are 2 cases:
1/

```
console.log(_.find(arr1,0,1));
console.log(_.find(arr2,0,1));
```

it return `undefined` with `arr2`
2/

```
console.log(_.find(arr1[1],0,1));
```

This one also returns `undefined`.
Can anyone tell me what I am missing here ?

**EDIT** 
For  `console.log(_.find(arr1,0,1));` I and @Mr.7 got 2 different results: the result I have on Chrome console is `[3,4]` but on `jsfiddle` is `[1,2]` which is the same as `Mr.7`. And I have noticed some thing strange in this `_.find`
Here is my code :

```
import _ from 'lodash';

const arr1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
const arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5];
const arr3 = [[0,2],[3,4],[5,6]];

console.log(_.find(arr1,1,1));//[3,4]
console.log(_.find(arr1,0,1));//[3,4]
console.log(_.find(arr2,2));//undefined
console.log(_.find(arr1,0));//[1,2]

console.log(_.find(arr3,0));//[3,4]
console.log(_.find(arr1,1));//[1,2]
```

Comment: 2nd case and first one of 1st case are same right? Both the cases returning `[1, 2]`

Comment: Sorry, I missed something. I have just updated

Comment: what do you want to do? by mean `_.find(arr2,0,1)` you are looking for `0` in `arr2` with starting index `1`, which will obviously be `undefined` https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#find

Comment: @Fahad he is not looking for `0` in `arr2`. `0` is the truth test. The function returns as soon as it finds an acceptable element, and doesn't traverse the entire list.

Comment: @Fahad no, I mean I am looking for the element with index `1`, that `0` is supposed to be a function invoked per iteration, but because there is no function here, so put `0`

Comment: ok, got it. what is the expected log ?

Comment: @Fahad in case #1 it should return the first index of each array. in case #2 it should return the first index of the first array of `arr1`

Comment: @JinDO I think it should return `undefined` only for all the cases, as long as you put `0` as predicate. since `0` is falsy, it should return `undefined` only. But i'm wondering why it is giving `[1, 2]` in first case

Comment: @JinDO read this link once http://underscorejs.org/#find

Comment: @Mr.7 `console.log(_.find(arr1,0,1));` returns [3,4] to me and it doesn't matter `0` or `1` they all return the same results

Comment: @JinDO Nope, it's giving `[1, 2]` only. can you please re-check once

Comment: @Mr.7 I have been checking this for hours and it is `[3,4]`, since the index is `1`, which is the second element

Comment: @JinDO check this fiddle once https://jsfiddle.net/Mr_7/3zwLmp51/

Comment: @JinDO why do you need `_.find` can't it simply be `arr1[0]` `arr2[0]` and case2 `arr1[0][0]` ? sorry I'm still confused what you are looking for, specific elements based on what, index or value?

Comment: @Mr.7 I got the same result as you do when run on `jsfiddle` but on Chrome I get [3,4]. Do you want to see my package.json ?

Comment: @JinDO till now i too checked on chrome only.and got the same result

Comment: @Fahad yeah that could have been easy but I'm trying to get to know the function. I'm trying to get the value based on the index

Comment: I have just updated a little bit. Can you please check ?

Comment: @Jin DO, your assumption with how this function works is incorrect. Proof of this is if you try and log: alert(_.find(arr1));.  You'll get the same result as if you log alert(_.find(arr1,1,2));.  Check out my answer again.

Comment: I've also just ran your updates.  _All_ alerts returned: 1,2

Comment: @Pineda I did not have the same results as you said. I have tried many times and it seems that the 3rd argument is the index not the 2nd. for `alert(_.find(arr1));` i have `[1,2]`  but `alert(_.find(arr1,1,2));` is [5,6]

Comment: @Pineda on `jsfiddle` i have the same results as you but not on my Chrome console

Comment: The 3rd argument can be an index, but you are passing the number 1 as a function to `.find`

Comment: @Pineda what do you suggest if I want to get the `2nd` element from the array ?

Comment: If you want to access the 2nd element of an array you don't need lodash: array[1] will work just fine.  I'll update my answer below with the lodash equivalent

Comment: @Pineda yes I know, but `_.find` is supposed to return the first element that match the condition, so I am trying to figure out if I can return the _2nd array_ from `arr1` by selecting the index

Comment: @Jin DO, again you are corerct.  How are you matching the condition?  You pass the index of 1 to get the 2nd element in the array as the **3rd** argument.  You have no condition for the **2nd** argument.  I've updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 5):

You are passing in a Number as a 2nd argument when:

> Lodash [`_.find()`](http://_.find()) **expects a `function` as its *2nd argument***
>   that is invoked per iteration.

The **function** passed in as a 2nd argument accepts three parameters:

- *value* - current value being iterated on
- *index|key* - the current index value for the array or key for a collection
- *collection* - a reference to the collection being iterated over

You are passing in the value of indexes where a function is required.

If you wanted to get the 2nd element in arr1 **you don't need lodash**, but can access direct using bracket notation and the index number:

```
arr1[1]
```

If you insist on using lodash, you can the 2nd element of arr1 as follows (although why you'd prefer this approach is questionable):

```
_.find(
     arr1,               // array to iterate over
     function(value, index, collection){   // the FUNCTION to use over each iteration
       if(index ===1)console.log(value)    // is the element at position 2?
     }, 
     1                   // the index of the array to start iterating from
   );                    // since you are looking for the element at position 2,
                         // this value 1 is passed, although with this set-up
                         // omitting won't break it but it would just be less efficient
```

Comment: actually I think the index comes last https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#find

Comment: _Not_ for the arguments that are passed to the function as the 2nd argument of `_.find()`

Comment: How do you do it in shorthand ?

Comment: You can use an arrow function and omit the collection argument to make things more compact.  If you feel that my answer has been helpful to you, then marking it as the accepted answer would be much appreciated.